# Remove draggable's helper clone on drop

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable

I have a draggable element with revert: true but when it gets successfully dropped, the helper clone remains on the droppable where I let go. I need the clone to disappear on the successfull drop just like it does on an unsuccessful drop.

```
$('.frank').draggable({ 
  revert: true,
  revertDuration: 0,
  helper: 'clone'
})

$( ".offer-2" ).droppable({
  accept: '.frank',
  drop: function() {
    $(this).addClass('offer-2b');
    $('.frank, .tp-2').draggable('disable');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can yust remove the helper in your drop function

```
$( ".offer-2" ).droppable({
    accept: '.frank',
    drop: handleDropEvent
});

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
    $(this).addClass('offer-2b');
    $('.frank, .tp-2').draggable('disable');
    $(ui.helper).remove();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the helper on the drop event:

```
$( ".offer-2" ).droppable({
  accept: '.frank',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass('offer-2b');
    ui.helper.hide();
  }
})
```

or if you really really don't need the dropped element then `ui.helper.remove()`

[jQuery Droppable drop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)